# Android - uses-permission to Download and save file in a specific Path

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

I would like create and save file in Download path on my Huawai (Android 8) App.

I'm on React Native app and i use `rn-fetch-blob` module.

My method :

```
const path = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir}/offer.txt`;

return RNFetchBlob.fs
  .writeFile(path, offer, 'utf8')
  .then(() => {
    alert('file create');
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

And the error message :

> { [Error: Permission denied] framesToPop: 1, code: 'EUNSPECIFIED' }

And my AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I don't understand why i've this permission error, all is good ?

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: you are having "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE " two times.remove one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android SDK versions greater then 23 you need to request permissions when they are needed at runtime through a dialog prompt. So you will have to use `PermissionsAndroid` from `react-native` in order to achieve that.

Something like

```
try {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      const granted = yield call(
        PermissionsAndroid.request,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
      ); // I used redux saga here. 'yield' keywoard. You don't have to use that. You can use async - await or Promises.

      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        // Your Save flow
      }
    } else {
      // iOS here, so you can go to your Save flow directly
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

You should take a look at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid

Answer (score 0):

For 6 and higher version you have to add permission run time.
You can use this pluging for adding permission.
[Permission plugin](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid)

Also you can check permission in Setting --> Application --> Your application -> Permissions